# Importing SDK into Vite bundle causes an error

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vuejs3, vite

I have downloaded the contents of `https://applepay.cdn-apple.com/jsapi/v1/apple-pay-sdk.js` and stored it within my Vue application in `src/sdk/apple-pay-sdk.js`

I'm importing the file in `main.ts` using:
`import './sdk/apple-pay-sdk'`

Which works fine, I can see the file in my built bundle.

However, on the browser I get a console error saying:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'src')`

How do I solve this?

Comment: What line of code is causing the error? Please [edit] your question to include the error stack trace

Comment: @Phil It's from the SDK, the line itself doesn't really help.

Comment: Yes, but a stack trace would also show what line of **your code** is triggering the error. At a guess, I'd say you're passing `null` into something that expects an `<img>` element